# What is the proper way to "combine" Docker images?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker. I've been trying to figure out how to "combine" multiple Docker images but I can't seem to find a straight answer. I've read on SO that adding multiple FROM statements is possible but discouraged.

For example, I want an image that features NGINX and MongoDB. Should I just copy-paste the contents of their official dockerfiles into one? What is the recommended way to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it makes sense to combine some services, e.g. nginx and a server-side script toolset, I would recommend against mixing a nginx and a mongodb container.

Instead, use each service in its own container and link the containers. To ease the process, I highly recommend reading up on [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/) in order to build a stack.

Answer (score 1):

Docker uses single inheritance rather than composition. And that is one of the missing features as for me.

That being said you should rarely need it at all, as you should run 1 thing on 1 container. So in your cases I would advise to use 2 images.

If you really need to run it on one, I would suggest to copy-paste configuration that makes NGINX installed on MongoDB base image or vice versa. Then add supervisord to run both

Comment: I ended up copy-pasting for now but as per @k0pernikus' suggestion, I plan to use docker-compose at a later time.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. That is the best long term plan and I would also suggest make it happen sooner rather than later as it should save you tons of troubles.